# Push a ViewController not through Storyboard while working with Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I searched the whole Internet for my question but obviously was to dumb to find anything.

In my app I'm working with a Storyboard and most of my ViewController are loaded in this style (I'm working with a navigation controller):

```
MyViewControllerClass *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

And now my question: Is it possible to push a VC in code without using storyboard for it? Like in the g'old times, but this does not work for me anymore:

```
MyViewControllerClass *viewController = [[MyViewControllerClass alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Please help me, I'm going crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: must add navigation into app delegate it will work ,, believe me

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does an empty view get pushed, or does nothing get pushed?

Comment: The push animations goes a little crazy and the pushed view is just black.

Comment: The funny animation/black view is because you haven't set your view up properly in code. Are you intending to create the view for this view controller entirely in code, or do you have a nib for it? Adding `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` to your view controller's `viewdidLoad` will stop this, but it might not fully fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it without using storyboard just you need to add navigation controller in app delegate like this, after that it will work fine

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create xib file and push it. You can't push without visual.

```
ViewControllernew* vv = (ViewControllernew*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewControllernew" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vv animated:YES];
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? I just want to create the interface in code, then create the instance and push it. Is this not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "You can't push without visual"?

Comment: Without xib file or storyboard.

Comment: You can create an instance of a view controller without loading the view from a xib or storyboard. You can create the view programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Can confirm it do work. 
Push will act this way if viewController is nil. Does your alloc init creates actually an instance?